# Circumcision for conjoined twins

Tags: halacha, number, brit-milah, parts-of-the-body, yoreh-deah

According to Halacha, if there are Jewish male conjoined twins, how many circumcisions are needed? Do both penises need it, or only one?

Comment: Are they both Jewish?

Comment: How many foreskins do they have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bais Yitzchak [YD 2 99:3](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=619&st=&pgnum=467) says that they would require two circumcisions. The reason is because the mitzvah is to remove the orlah, and since there’s two, they both must be removed. However, tefillin is a mitzvah on the person, not the head, and therefore the Gemara questions if he’s one person or two in that regard but for a bris it is clear that he would need two.